# Automated Tests of Custom Controls

Tags: wpf, testing, custom-controls

What options do I have to automate tests for the various aspects of my custom WPF controls, such as:

1. Layout behavior
2. input and user interaction behavior
3. general apperance

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used them but a couple of options are [White](http://white.codeplex.com/) and [UIA Verify](http://uiautomationverify.codeplex.com/). Otherwise I think you're currently limited to using the UI Automation framework directly or comparing images.

Comment: I wonder if there is some way to verify the visual appearance (e.g. dimensions of the controls and their colors, icons etc.).